Dynamically tooltip placement poisition changed in maui app
Currently I have migrating xamarin to MAUI app. To customize the tooltip placement position in maui no more change the tooltip placement. How to customize the control to change the tooltip placement position and background color. If any samples it will be helpful and highly appreciated.

To change the tooltip placement position and background color, you can do it by adding the following code to your Platforms/Windows/App.xaml:
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Setter Property="Placement"  Value="Right"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>

